# Cygwin SSH for multiple users

Tags: cygwin, sshd

I configured cygwin's SSHD service on two windows sever(2008) with USER1 
I can successfully connect/SSH from/to each server with USER1.
What changes i need to make if i want to connect/SSH to server with other account say USER2?
Is it possible at all like in my case i have set up SSHD with USER1?